# ec2 list my snapshots and owner id

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

If I call describeSnapshots() of AmazonEC2 Java interface I get a big number of snapshots as described in the documentation, because it includes all visible snapshots.

However to get the list of my snapshots, should be easy with the API, but it isn't obvious to me. I tried to pass a DescribeSnapshotsRequests object to describeSnapshots()

```
DescribeSnapshotsRequest req = new DescribeSnapShotRequests();
List<String> ownerId = new ArrayList<String>();
ownerId.add("....");
req.setOwnerIds(ownerId);
DescribeSnapshotsResult res = ec2.describeSnapshots(req);
```

However to get my user id, I printed the user id of all snapshots and manually identified mine, copied that user id, and used in the source code.

I hope there is a better way to list my snapshots, anyone knows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
 req.setOwnerIds(Arrays.<String>asList("self"));
```

Something like this works for me to describe images.

Comment: Yes works for me too, thanks. A pity that is not described in the Javadoc of setOwnerIds(), it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html

> If you specify one or more snapshot owners using the OwnerIds option,
>   only snapshots from the specified owners and for which you have access
>   are returned. The results can include the AWS account IDs of the
>   specified owners, amazon for snapshots owned by Amazon, or self for
>   snapshots that you own.

```
ec2.describeSnapshots(new DescribeSnapshotsRequest().withOwnerIds("self"));
```